# Why is the struct type UUID not sendable?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Given that type UUID is a struct I thought it would be `Sendable`. But the compiler generates a warning:

```swift
struct S: Sendable {
    var int: Int
    var id: UUID // <-- Stored property 'id' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'S' has non-sendable type 'UUID'
}
```

Comment: struct are not automatically conforming to Sendable. Maybe the UUID reference to [C code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/include/swift/Basic/UUID.h) for generating the unique identifier is what stops it from conforming to Sendable

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```swift
struct S: Sendable {
    var int: Int
    var id: UUID
}

extension UUID: UnsafeSendable { }
```

Xcode tells me to use `@unchecked Sendable` instead of `UnsafeSendable` but it doesn't recognize `@unchecked` yet.